# Actualizar datos si son iguales MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Buen día gente, tengo la siguiente situación, estoy trabajando en el back de un CRUD, resulta que para hacer la función de UPDATE debo validar si, los valores que ingresa el usuario su sumatoria es igual a la sumatoria de la DB. Es decir, la suma de los valores capturados por el usuario, debe ser igual a la de la Base de datos.  Como dato, esta función se llama dentro de otra que tengo.

```
public function checkCantidad ($item, $devolverDatos){
        $datosError = new \stdClass;
        if(isset($item['valor1']) && isset($item['valor2']) && isset($item['valor3'])
        && isset($item['valor4']) && isset($item['valor5']) && isset($item['valor6'])){
            $query = "SELECT 
            SUM(valor1+valor2+valor3+valor4+valor5+valor6) as total 
            FROM tabla1 where id= {$item['id']}
            if (total <> total = 'Error')
            ";
        }else{
                $datosError->status = 1;
                $datosError->mensaje = "La suma no coincide con el registrado";
                $devolverDatos->push($datosError);
                return $item = 0;
        }
        return $item;

    }
```

Este es mi código, actualmente si actualizo la información aunque su suma no sea igual lo actualiza, la idea es que actualice siempre y cuando la suma sea igual.

Comment: El select te muestra un campo suma de los campos, donde el id sea el del usuario. Eso, si existe el usuario te devolverá la suma. lo que tú pides es que el WHERE tenga dos condiciones, el id y que la suma sea correcta. En este caso probablemente necesites un HAVING para la condición, puesto que es de una operación SUM (aunque no estoy muy seguro)

Comment: Si, osea, tengo un id que captura el usuario junto con esa suma, cada usuario tiene su propia suma, la idea es que si el quiere cambiar el orden de los valores lo pueda hacer, pero el resultado no se puede ver alterado. Como puedo realizar eso con el Having?